# Different results from binary and categorical crossentropy

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I made an experiment between the usage of `binary_crossentropy` and `categorical_crossentropy`. I try to understand the behavior of these two loss functions on same problem.

I worked on `binary classification` problem with this [data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv).

In the first experiment, I used `1` neuron in the last layer with `sigmoid` activation function and `binary_crossentropy`. I trained this model 10 times and take the average accuracy. The average accuracy is 74.12760416666666.

The code that I used for first experiment is below.

```
total_acc = 0
for each_iter in range(0, 10):
    print each_iter
    X = dataset[:,0:8]
    y = dataset[:,8]
    # define the keras model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    # compile the keras model
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # fit the keras model on the dataset
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=32)
    # evaluate the keras model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
    temp_acc = accuracy*100
    total_acc += temp_acc

    del model
```

In the second experiment, I used `2` neurons in the last layer with `softmax` activation function and `categorical_crossentropy`. I converted my target `y, into categorical and again I trained this model 10 times and take the average accuracy. The average accuracy is 66.92708333333334.

The code that I used for the second setting is in below:

```
total_acc_v2 = 0
for each_iter in range(0, 10):
    print each_iter
    X = dataset[:,0:8]
    y = dataset[:,8]
    y = np_utils.to_categorical(y)
    # define the keras model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(8, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
    # compile the keras model
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
    # fit the keras model on the dataset
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=150, batch_size=32)
    # evaluate the keras model
    _, accuracy = model.evaluate(X, y)
    print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))
    temp_acc = accuracy*100
    total_acc_v2 += temp_acc
    del model
```

I think that these two experiments are identical and should give very similar results. What is the reason of this huge difference between accuracy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the reason of such behaviour is randomness. I've ran your code and got around 74 average accuracy for the *sigmoid model* and around 74 for the *softmax model*.

Comment: Here's my try https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z9ZbeLTT0U923GlkNBlkdJfzMr6HaRys?usp=sharing

Comment: It is a surprising thing for me. I iterate the code 10 times to handle this randomness but it seems it is not enough. So, based on your result, we can work in both ways for binary classification problems?

Comment: Yes, we can. But the good practice is to use _sigmoid function_ in binary classification